# How to create routes in node js application

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, routes, node-modules

Iam completely stuck and finally came here in hope of someone helping.Iam creating a node js app and got a sample app using express generator commands.Now I need 3 routes mainly

```
1.localhost:3000
2.localhost:3000/login
3.localhost:3000/home
```

For these I created 3 html files and placed these inside `public/views folder`

Basically on running my app it should take me to main page.where it will have button and onclick it takes me to /login page and on successful credentials,it should take me to /home page.

For login I wrote a rest call but I need to use that

Here I need help

1.How to provide routes from my main app.js(server side) and load these files according to the routes we get.

2.From my html I need to call post call,for which I will use ajax.For this I need to have js file where can I add that?

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 2):

In express framework you can do it like this

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
app.get("/login",function(request,response){

     response.sendFile("login.html",root:{"./"});
      });
```